# Wordpress Bootstrap - inline margin-top

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

before i going to be crazy, i ask you now. 
Currently i customize a wordpress theme with bootstraps included.
The main/index-page looks great.
But the subpages which have another top-menue make trouble.
Everytime i load a subpage (not in chache) the content appears under the top-menue and drops down to the correct position afterwards. 
I saw in the chrome developer tools that there is a padding-top declaration in the body-class-element. 
As i think it is in relation with bootstrap i checked all css and js file of it. But i can't found an answer to prevent or fix that.

**EDIT**

Here is the code of the header.php. At the top of the file after the < /head > you see the body_class which makes the problems and give them the padding-top value of 84px. Direct below is the the branch of the menu-items.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<?php apex_favicon(); ?>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <?php
    $settings = apex_section_settings();
    if( $settings['page_top'] == 'header' ) {
        get_template_part( 'templates/elements/header' );
    } elseif( $settings['page_top'] == 'hero' ) {
        get_template_part( 'templates/elements/hero' );
    }
    ?>

    <?php global $apex_general_settings; ?>

    <header id="site-navigation" class="apex-style-<?php echo $apex_general_settings['navigation_style']; ?>">
    <div id="site-navigation-contents">
      <div class="container">

                <?php echo get_apex_menu_logo(); ?>

                <a id="mobile-menu-toggle" href="#"><i class="apex-icon-mobile-menu"></i></a>

                <?php
                $args = array(
                    'theme_location'        => 'apex-primary-menu',
                    'menu_class'                => 'apex-primary-menu clearfix',
                    'container'                 => 'nav',
                    'container_class'       => 'apex-primary-menu-container',
                    'fallback_cb'               => 'primary_menu_fallback',
                    'walker'                    => new Apex_Icon_Menu_Walker()
                );
                wp_nav_menu( $args );
                ?>

            </div><!-- .container -->
    </div><!-- #site-navigation-contents -->
  </header><!-- #site-navigation -->

  <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="main" role="main">
```

Some screenshots of the developer tools:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD2xg.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/81vaJ.png

Code-snippet of the menu-part of the js-file:

```
/* --------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* !Main menu position - 1.0.0 */
    /* --------------------------------------------------------- */

    function apex_visible_menu_height() {
        $('body').css('paddingTop', nav_h+'px');
    }

    function apex_hidden_menu_reset() {
        $nav_contents.stop().css({
            marginTop: -nav_h+'px'
        });

        nav_visible = true;
    }

    function apex_hidden_menu_display( top ) {

        if( !nav_visible && top > nav_offset ) {

            nav_visible = true;

            $nav_contents.stop().animate( {
                marginTop: 0
            }, 700, 'easeOutQuint', function() {
                nav_h = $nav_contents.outerHeight(true);
                if( $admin_bar.length > 0 ) {
                    nav_h += $admin_bar.outerHeight(true);
                }
            });

        } else if( nav_visible && top < nav_offset ) {

            nav_visible = false;

            $nav_contents.stop().animate( {
                marginTop: '-'+nav_h+'px'
            }, 700, 'easeOutQuint', function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });

            if( is_mobile ) {
                apex_mobile_menu_hide( true );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your code so that we can help.

Comment: Which part of the code do you need especially? Or it's better for you to get a link of the webpage?

Comment: atleast the top menu that is causing the problem with bootstrap cdn s

Comment: I edited the post and added some code. I'm not shure if this is enough to help